# Accounts Payables and Receivables

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, accounts

I have enabled Multiple companies feature in OpenERP. While creating Supplier for a company, it shows the following message.

1. Accounts Payable is invalid,
2. Accounts Receivable is invalid.

Can someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Check if property fields are set properly. 
Is problem only when you create new supplier? If yes, I bet there is a problem with default for this fields.